# Euclidean distance for vectors stored in MultiValue field

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 5.5 and I have a problem with function [dist](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#dist). In Solr admin, at the query page, when I provide in the "fl" field this function for "static" values, I get the right results, for example:

```
dist(2, 1, 2, 2, 1)
```

gives me some distance. But when I try to use this function with data stored in one of my fields, for example:

```
dist(2, first_vector, 0.445, 0.332, 0.778)
```

it gives me error "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field".
In field "first_vector" I have a list of floats, looking like this:

```
first_vector: [0.334, 0.883, 0.2223]
```

In schema.xml field type is float, and multivalued is set to True.

Should I store this data in other way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which of the values from first_vector do you want to use?

Comment: @MatsLindh all. Values in "first_vector" creates the vector, which I want to compare with vector given by me. I have a lot of documents, containing vectors in "first_vector" field, and I want to find nearest distance between given vector, and each vector I have in "first_vector" field.

Comment: OK - the value won't be expanded across the argument list (so it is parsed as 2, [...], 0.445, ..). You might have more luck by representing the points as actual points with Solr's PointType?